# In Excel formula cell, is there a way to programmatically change the expression from using default variables to customized cell names?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with thousands of formula cells. For example,

```
E1=A1+B1+C1*D1, E2=A2+B2+C2*D2, E3=A3+B3+C3*D3, E4=A4+B4+C4*D4, ....
 .... E5000=A5000+B5000+C5000*D5000
```

I used this code below to change the names of the relevant cells.

```
colV = 1
    For c = cFrom To cTo 
            Rowv = 1
            For r = row1 To row5000 
               With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)                
                        Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(r, c).Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "R" & Rowv & "C" & colV
                        Rowv = Rowv + 1                
               End With
            Next r
            colV = colV + 1
    Next c
```

After the execution of the above code, the new names for A1, B1, C1, D1 and E1 are now Sheet1R1C1, Sheet1R1C2, Sheet1R1C3, Sheet1R1C4, Sheet1R1C5, respectively, which is expected and correct. The same rule applies to succeeding rows.

But when I see the formulas in the formula bar in all rows in column E, the original/default expression is retained. For example the formula of the cell E1 is still =A1+B1+C1*D1, E2 is still =A2+B2+C2*D2 and so on. Is there a way to express the formula in terms of the new name of the cells programmatically? For example, the E1 should be expressed as = Sheet1R1C1+Sheet1R1C2+Sheet1R1C3*Sheet1R1C4,
E2 should be expressed as = Sheet1R2C1+Sheet2R2C2+Sheet1R2C3*Sheet1R2C4 and so on. This is needed because the new expression using the updated cell names will be stored in the csv.

The

```
FormulaVar = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Cells(r, c).Formula
```

yields original expression

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select *Formulas* > *Define Name* > *Apply Names*
  [image]
- In the dialog that pops up select all the names and press OK:
  [image]
- Your `=A1+B1+C1` should now read `=Sheet1R1C1+Sheet1R1C2+Sheet1R1C3`

The VBA for this is below, but will throw an error if there aren't any references to find.

```
Sub Test()

    Cells.ApplyNames Names:=Array("Sheet1R1C1", "Sheet1R1C2", "Sheet1R1C3", "Sheet1R1C4")

End Sub
```

After updating the formula then the code `Debug.Print Cells(1, 4).Formula` returned *=Sheet1R1C1+Sheet1R1C2+Sheet1R1C3*.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked like magic! There are actually and literally hundreds of thousands of formula cells that I have to deal with in different excel sheets. I thought I need to hard code everything using parsing and lots of coding. Again thank you very much!

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to tick the answer as accepted. :)